# Is there a way to unmap in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a Haskell program. I've created a data type called measurement which is an array of doubles, it looks like this:

```
data Measurement = Measurement [Double]  deriving (Show)
```

I have a function to cast to Measurement, it takes a list of lists of doubles and will cast it to a list of Measurements. It looks like this:

```
castToMeasurement :: [[Double]] -> [Measurement]
castToMeasurement = map Measurement
```

But now I want to do some opereations on the double values. So is there a way I can unmap to an array of doubles? So when I give it a Measurement (or list of Measurements), it will cast it to a list of Doubles (or a list of lists of double). Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you have `data MyType = SingleConstructor ExistingType` or `data MyType parameter = SingleConstructor (ExistingTypeExpression parameter)` you should usre a newtype like `newtype MyType = SingleConstructor {getSingleConstructor :: ExistingType}` etc.. A `newtype` declaration works very similarly to a `data` declaration, except that because only one constructor is allowed, the compiler can implement the error-avoiding compile-time type safety but with `SingleConstructor` and `getSingleConstructor` implemented as no-ops so there's zero runtime space or time impact.

Comment: Note that `Measurement` holds a *list*, not an *array*. These are very different structures in Haskell. Also, you should consider switching from `data` to `newtype` in situations like this, because `newtype` can give asymptotically better performance for things like `castToMeasurement`, especially in bleeding-edge GHC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
data Measurement = Measurement { getMeasurement :: [Double] } deriving Show

castToMeasurement :: [[Double]] -> [Measurement]
castToMeasurement = map Measurement

castFromMeasurement :: [Measurement] -> [[Double]]
castFromMeasurement = map getMeasurement
```

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: It really is simple. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, maybe one more question. What is the getMeasurement for?

Comment: Oh, I am too late with my answer :D

Comment: @MaartenMeeusen you should read about record syntax: [here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor) or [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)

Comment: @arunasr I think it's perfectly justified. What's wrong with using the record syntax for just 1 field? I've seen it used many times in the standard libraries. Example: `newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }`, as seen here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/src/Data-Functor-Identity.html. Why use pattern matching to manually define a function which you can get for free using the record syntax? Also, you can't pattern match on `castFromMeasurement` because the input is a list (i.e. `[Measurement]`). You can't define a `Functor` instance of `Measurement`.

Comment: @AaditMShah agreed. Sorry, was a rush comment without enough thinking.

Answer (score 6):

Well, no and yes.

The way you phrase the question, whether there's a way to "unmap," the answer would have to be no, not in general.  Suppose we have a list of strings:

```
example1 :: [String]
example1 = ["Hello", "cruel", "world"]
```

We can use `map length` to map this to the lengths of the strings:

```
example2 :: [Int]
example2 = map length example
-- value: [5, 5, 5]
```

But there is no way to "unmap" the value of `example2` to get back the original `example1`.  That would require there to be a function that, given the length, figured out which string the original list had—but that is clearly insufficient information!

But this gives us a hint about  what sort of situation we can perform the "unmapping" that you want. If the function that we originally mapped with has an **inverse**, then we can map with that inverse to "undo" the effect of `map`.  In your case, the `Measurement` constructor does have an inverse:

```
-- | The inverse of the 'Measurement' constructor.  Laws:
--
-- > Measurement (getMeasurement x) == x
-- > getMeasurement (Measurement xs) == xs
getMeasurement :: Measurement -> [Double]
getMeasurement (Measurement xs) = xs
```

Since `Measurement` and `getMeasurement` are inverses it follows that `map Measurement` and `map getMeasurement` are as well, and so:

```
map getMeasurement (map Measurement xs) == xs
map Measurement (map getMeasurement xs) == xs
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can. [Here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Deconstructing_data_constructors) you can read more about it.

Let think about the function `f`:

```
f :: [Double] -> Measurement
f list = Measurement list
```

It just wraps the constructor of `Measurement`. I am using new function because it is much easier for me to think about function than about constructors.

Now you need the inverse function to `f`:

```
g :: Measurement -> [Double]
g (Measurement list) = list
```

So now you can construct function:

```
castFromMeasurement :: [Measurement] -> [[Double]]
castFromMeasurement = map g
```

It looks a bit ugly. So we can modify it using lambdas:

```
castFromMeasurement :: [Measurement] -> [[Double]]
castFromMeasurement = map (\(Measurement list) -> list)
```

But notice that it works only when your data type is not abstract (you have full access to constructor). Also you can redefine your data as follows:

```
data Measurement = Measurement { getMeasurement :: [Double] } deriving Show
```

In this case you already have function `g = getMeasurement`. So `castFromMeasurement` looks like:

```
castFromMeasurement :: [Measurement] -> [[Double]]
castFromMeasurement = map getMeasurement
```

---

More generally, you can `unmap` if and only if function `f` you used to map is reversable.

Answer (score 3):

You got an answer to your question but let's bring math to the table and learn when and how it's possible to unmap.

We're pure functional programmers; that means that the functions we write are very mathematical (which is beyond awesome for many reasons, one of them: it's possible to write this answer). When dealing with functions, the function domain is every possible value of the input type (+ bottom for boxed types). The range, likewise, is every possible value of the output type.

What you are basically asking for is an [inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) for the function in your example (`fmap Measurement`).
An inverse function for function will "undo" what that function "did".
If I have value `x` and function `f`, and the inverse function of `f` is `g`, then by definition `x = f(g(x))) = g(f(x)))`. This is probably gibberish, so think about the functions `f = (+1)` and `g = subtract 1`, and pick any integer for `x`. Let's say `x=5` for example. `f(5) = 6`, and now notice how when you apply `g` -- `g(6) = 5` -- you got the number you started off with.
You "undid" `f` by applying the result to `g`, because `g` is the inverse of `f`.

Some functions don't have an inverse function (as Luis Casillas demonstrated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27711280/825637) here).
When your function does have, it's up to you to find it. If indeed possible, it's usually it's as difficult as the function you're inversing (e.g. like in the above, plus becomes minus. Like in your example too - your function was simple so the inverse was bound to also be simple).

An easy way to tell if there's an inverse function is to see if there exists a [one-to-one mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) between the domain and the range. If there isn't - you lost data when you applied the function and you can't go back. So if an inverse function doesn't exist and you still need to go back, you should find other means. E.g. zip the original value before-hand (`(x, f x)`), and to get to the original value just apply `fst`.

[Inverse Functions on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/algebra-functions/function_inverses/v/introduction-to-function-inverses)
[Inverse Functions on TheMathPage](http://www.themathpage.com/aprecalc/inverse-functions.htm)
[Inverse Functions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function)